# How can I fopen a file in C using Visual Studio?

Tags: c, fopen, binaryfiles

I want to open a file "3.bin" with a C code like below:

```
//ProgramReport3.c
const char* fileName = "3.bin";
unsigned int data;
unsigned int addr;
unsigned int iCount;    // # of instructions
unsigned int dCount;    // # of data
err = fopen_s(&pFile, fileName, "rb");
printf("%d",err);
if (err) {
    printf("Cannot open file: %s\n", fileName);
    return 1;
}
```

When I use visual studio code, I just put "3.bin" file in same folder with main.c file: [image: See here]

But when I use visual studio, I put ProgramReport3.c file in source folder, and I put 3.bin file in resource file folder but I get below error:

`Cannot find 3.bin file`

How can I run this code with visual studio??

After I get below comments,
I move bin file to same folder where project.exe file is.

(I try to find main.c(in my case ProgramReport3.c)'s exe file
I can't find...so I put bin file with project.exe file)

but still it's not working..how can I do next??
Thanks a lot

[image: I put bin file and project.exe file together]

Comment: Where is `main.c`?

Comment: And where is `3.bin`?

Comment: What is working directory when you run your program?

Comment: Sorry, ProgramReport3.cpp file is main.c :( I edit !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VS, the "3.bin" file needs to be in the same folder as the created executable file - not as the main C-file. This is usually a subfolder of the project folder.

If you do not want to do this manually, you can set the "Copy to Output Directory" property of the file to "Copy Always" in visual studio, so that after the build succeeds, the file is copied to the output directory automatically.

Comment: More generally, it needs to be in the current working directory. For a program invoked from VS, that's usually the directory containing the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my error!
I run code that create file

```
fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
```

and I check above directory (mouse right click -> open folder in file explorer)
so I can get position

Thank you for answer!! I helped a lot:)
[image]